# C++: Strange virtual member function pointers in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, pointer-to-member

I am just puzzled by the following:

```
struct InterfaceABC {
    virtual int printPolymorphic(int a) {
        return a;
    }
}

struct WithInterfaces : public InterfaceABC {
    virtual int printPolymorphic(int a) { return a; }
};
```

When I now do:

```
address = &WithInterfaces::printPolymorphic;
```

I get this in the debugger:

```
0x012e52a9 {unittests.exe![thunk]:MockMe::WithInterfaces::`vcall'{4,{flat}}' }'}
```

BUT, the following invokation will not land there:

```
((InterfaceABC*) new WithInterfaces())->printPolymorphic(3);
```

After a day of effort I found out how to "reliably" (famous last words) get the real virtual address using C++ code, which gives me:

```
0x012e6ece {unittests.exe!MockMe::WithInterfaces::printPolymorphic(int)}
```

So what do we have here?

```
WithInterfaces().printPolymorphic(3)
```

Will be calling

```
0x012e6ece {unittests.exe!MockMe::WithInterfaces::printPolymorphic(int)}
```

And so will

```
((InterfaceABC*)new WithInterfaces())->printPolymorphic(3);
```

...

Visual Studio implements the stub function justfor me :) huh? I feel flattered... but

```
address = &WithInterfaces::printPolymorphic;
```

this will not at all give you the function address. It will give you an address to a function that is never called and can never be called without hackery.

Anyone has some great ideas as to why this is? And maybe also some ideas about how to REALLY get the real address without writing about 100 lines scary C++ madness that probably no one but me understands from all the people that will be reviewing the code? That is, in a standard compliant way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the address of `WithInterfaces::printPolymorphic` gives you back a thunk that, when invoked, dispatches to the correct function to call based on the type of the object.

If you call a virtual member function on an object, the compiler emits code to look up a pointer to the correct implementation in the virtual function table (`vtable`) of the object and then invokes that function.

A pointer to a virtual member function encapsulates this behavior, which you made explicit by looking at the generated thunk.

> > It will give you an address to a function that is never called and can never be called without hackery.

The logic for it, however, is contained in every single call to a virtual function.

Comment: Hmm dumb me... Right, if you pass that address to something it doesn't know that its a virtual function. So it will just pass the object pointer and then the thunk will do the vtable thingy. Seems somewhat logical. At least my day of effort was not wasted then. Thanks for this clarification!